# Can't get Response From Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Can't get responce from Following ajax Script That Call Php Script that Echo Cost Of Given Item name

```
function ajaxfunc2(Item_name)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
     document.getElementById("cost").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    }

xmlhttp.open("GET","find.php?Item="+Item_name,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

But I will Get Output from Php File

with this link

```
127.0.0.1:8888/Pharmaceutical Distribution System/PDS/find.php?Item=1st tshirt
```

Comment: Also, make sure to check the `readyState` of the `xmlhttp` object to be 4.

Comment: Thank You  @JameyD !  But Problem Is Still Same.

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Look at the Developer Tools in your browser. Check the Console for error messages. Check the Net tab to see if the request is going to the RUL you expect and if you get the response you expect.

Comment: @Quentin I debug but Google Chrome console didn't Get Any Message!

Comment: What about the Net tab? Do you see the request? Do you get the response you expect?

Comment: I can't Understand Anything Displayed In Network Tab